# Servlet doesn't find CSS

Tags: css, servlets

I have a servlet in a folder, and my "css" folder two folders behind. When I run my servlet appears without the css.

My code for css into the servlet is :

```
link rel='stylesheet' href='../../css/file.css' type='text/css'
```

My folder structure :

"main_folder" -> "css" and "servlet0" .

"servlet0" -> "servlet1" which contains the servlet file

Comment: Add your folders structure in the question please

Comment: I added the structure of folders

Comment: Use the Net tab of your browser's developer tools. What URL does the stylesheet resolve as? What do you get when you request that URL directly?

Comment: Exactly, Quentin comment should make it clearier why they are not found.